# How would I properly style the nav bar to be closer to the edge

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm having issues with my nav bar, I'm wondering how I can make the set closer to the left most edge.

CSS:

```
#nav
{
   overflow: auto;        
   user-select: none;
   background: grey;
   width: 100%;
}
#nav li
{
   display: inline-block;
   list-style-type: none;   /* removes bullets */
   padding: 10px;            
   margin: 0px;             /* removes margins */
   background: grey;
}
#nav li:hover
{
   background: green;
   user-select: green;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yumyum0/cgx61w0q/2/

Also, I'm not sure if the background and user select in the #nav li:hover is redundant. I'm modeling it off of the tutorial on https://html.com/css/#example-nav, and I started to add things to try and style it the way I wanted. I'm still a long ways away from knowing what all of the declarations do. It used to be flush so I think I probably added something that has a conflict, or I removed it without knowing.

I also had a question that wasn't really related to this, is this formatting okay? I wasn't sure if there was a agreed upon way with brackets and everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good thing to do is set the styles for the HTML and Body tags. This is what I would do:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0; // Removes space on the sides
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#nav 
{
  overflow: auto;
  user-select: none;
  background: grey;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box; // Add this to take 100% width without overflowing
  margin: 0; // Remove space above nav bar
}

...rest of your CSS
```

Answer (score 1):

Placing this ruleset at the start of your code will remove the margins at the top of your navbar.

```
* {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 0;
}
```

Your formatting is slightly off; place the opening bracket on the same line as the CSS selector, and make sure there is a gap between rulesets, for greater readability.

Comment: This helps a lot, thanks! I'll make sure to do this from now on.

Comment: Just to clarify, what you mean by on the same line is demonstrated in your example?

Answer (score 0):

You can position absolute and declare it must be at the left most point of the page.

```
#nav 
{
  overflow: auto;
  user-select: none;
  background: grey;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

Styling your code is up to you! I like keeping the name in the same line as the curly bracket like `#nav {`

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigation spacing: One thing to research is a solution called "[CSS Reset](https://cssdeck.com/blog/what-is-a-css-reset/)". Browsers like Chrome and Firefox have different "base values" for HTML selectors. A reset stylesheet ensures that all of your elements will have the same "base" styles. There are 1000 different reset sheets out there that different people have attempted. They all roughly do the same thing in my opinion.The `<body>` tag has margin assigned to it by default. A reset sheet would normally assign these to 0 amongst other things.
2. Kind of the same thing as above, the `<ul>` tag also has margin on it by default. You should add in the following CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

#nav 
{
  background: grey;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

3. Let's discuss the `user-select` property. This property is what you would use in order to target a "highlight" or "text select" for a copy/paste situation on a webpage. I do not think this is what you should be using for a "hover" effect. You should be just fine with using the `background` property.

Comment: That's good to know that it's default. About "3." (on your list): when I did the "user-select", my intention behind it was so users couldn't select/highlight it. I kind of just threw it in there to see what it would do, and noticed that I wasn't able to highlight it. I guess it doesn't really matter, does the background property already do that? Meaning "user-select" is redundant?